# Python's ftplib corrupting sent files - Winsock issue?

Tags: python, winsock2, ftplib

We have a Python application we used to transfer source files back and forth between SVN checkouts on our PC and an [IBM i](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_i) midrange system.

It has been in use for a number of years with no issues.

Recently, we've started seeing source file get corrupted when sent from the PC to IBM i. The lines are out of order on the destination. [Wireshark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) shows that the data is leaving the PC out of order.

Sometimes it works fine, sometimes it's one or two lines out of order, and other times it's lots of lines.

The script had not changed prior to this issue appearing.

This is the `storlines()` invocation in the Python code:

```
connection.storlines('STOR ' + ibmi_file, open(source_file.fullpath, 'rb'))
```

Originally, I was using Python 2.7.12 on Windows 10. I tried upgrading to 2.7.13, but still I see the issue. I tried moving to 3.6.1, but I still see the issue.

Other developers are also seeing this issue, running various versions of Python and Windows.

I downloaded the 3.6.1 source and added some debug logging to sock_sendall() and sock_send_impl() in socketmodule.c

I can see the following being sent from sock_send_impl().

Source 
line#  - length (bytes) 
1 - 79 
2 - 73 
3 - 38 
4 - 73 
5 - 78 
6 - 41

Wireshark shows the following FTP data packets.

Packet# - FTP Data length 
1 - 79 
2 - 1452

The problem is that packet 2 starts out with source lines:

2, 5, 3, 4

As I understand it, sock_send_impl() is where the data is handed off to the OS. I realize [Nagle's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) is used to combine the little sends into one larger TCP packet.

But the data in that packet should be in the same order as it was passed into send. And it's not.

I thought it might be related to some recent Windows patch, except that one of our developers using a Mac is seeing the same(?) issue.

We do have one developer running Windows 7 who at least report hadn't seen the issue (he's been out).

It doesn't make any sense to me, and I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're reasonably sure the issue was cause by version 14.6 MP1 of Symantec Vontu; which is a Data Loss Prevention (DLP) product that "inspects" packets before they leave the PC.

I believe the issue was reported to Symantec.

In the meantime, we worked around the issue by extending the base `ftplib.FTP` class and adding a new function:

```
#stortext combines block read from STORBINARY with ASCII transfer mode from STORLINE
def stortext(self, cmd, fp, blocksize=8192, callback=None, rest=None):
    self.voidcmd('TYPE A')
    conn = self.transfercmd(cmd, rest)
    while 1:
        buf = fp.read(blocksize)
        if not buf: break
        conn.sendall(buf)
        if callback: callback(buf)
    conn.close()
    return self.voidresp()
```

We stopped having issues with scrambled code.  As a bonus, the transfer run considerably faster than they did with `storline`.

So we've continued to use our new function.